# According to Markovnikov rule and stability of carbocation which is most likely to form if HI "excess" is not given?

Tags: organic-chemistry

#### Problem

> [image: 3‐iodoprop‐1‐ene + HI + CCl4]

#### Answer                          > [image: 1,2‐diiodopropane]

I thought "I" can stabilizes carbocation formed intially by resonance so there can be a shift of (+) to the carbon close to "I" and hence forming the product 1,1-diiodopropane but given is 1,2 product , whats wrong in this ? Or is that H+ and +I combined effect of CH3 is slightly greater than compared to resonance of "I"?

Comment: yes! the inductive effect of halogens is a special case. That it overweighs their +R

Comment: No exception? In any case?

Comment: not that I know of, but I believe there must be some exception as in almost all concepts, we get to see at least one exception in chemistry. Someone who has more idea about this might be able to help

Comment: Do you know two -OH groups on a single carbon are unstable? And here we have I atoms! In fact, how would you explain the formation of 2-iodopropane when excess HI is taken?

Comment: What the OP is asking is that could the carbocation shift to the carbon to which the I is initially attached, then we could get a 1,1 di iodo product

Comment: @WayBig, Is it HI in excess?

Comment: @PrajwalTiwari https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72156/mechanism-of-the-reaction-of-an-alkene-with-excess-hi-in-presence-of-ccl4

Comment: @Safdar Faisal Not excess pls read the title of the question

Comment: Yeah ik @Light Yagami , i was just asking one step before that elimination thing happens which is the cause for 2 iodopropane .  And i was asking in case someone who dont know about the excess product and was just given this as problem then what would he be guessing nothing more

Comment: Exactly @Prajwal Tiwari  and i see i was just asking if u have encountered any exceptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three reasons as far as I can see as to why the 1,2 product is favored. There may be more.

1. *Steric hindrance*

   The iodine atom is large in size compared to the carbon atom. Having two iodine atoms on successive carbon atoms in a hydrocarbon is quite unstable. In fact, should two successive carbon atoms possess iodine substituents, they usually undergo elimination reactions. And here the 1,1 product would have two iodine groups on the *same* carbon atom!
2. *Inductive effect of halogens*

   While it is true that halogen atoms have a positive mesomeric effect, this effect is almost always dominated by their negative inductive effect. If you see a halogen atom, you can usually neglect it's +M effects in favor of it's −I effects.
3. *Carbocation stability*

   The carbocation formed in the process of formation of the 1,2 product is more stable (due to hyperconjugation) than the one formed in the process of formation of the 1,1 product (again, due to the −I effect of iodine).

Either way,  1,2-diiodopropane is more stable than  1,1-diiodopropane.

Comment: Ty i got your pt one more thing wanted to ask any exceptions uk when that -I of halogens fails over +M ?

Comment: @WayBig I have not heard on any exception.

Comment: I see , Can u check this link out too its regarding same reaction type ? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149835/106350